# Post image as base64 string from Titanium app to Ruby on rails web service

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image-processing, titanium, base64

I'm having a problem posting an image from an app that has been converted to a base64 string to a ruby on rails server.

The app is written using Titanium.
The the image sting is retrieved it is and turned back into an image there is no image.
The app function doing the conversion and sending it is as follows 

    `function postActivity() {`

```
//hide keyboard on submit
Ti.UI.Android.hideSoftKeyboard();

var imgFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(img);
var imgString = imgFile.read();

var mybase = Ti.Utils.base64encode(imgString);

sendData('POST', 'create_post.json', true, jsonToForm({
    "post[text1]" : $.txt1.value,
    "post[number1]" : $.number1.value,
    "post[time]" : (60 * parseInt($.txtHrs.value)) + parseInt($.txtMins.value),
    "post[comment]" : $.txtComments.value,
    "post[image64]" : mybase.toString()
}), function(response) {
    alert('Activity Added.');

    Ti.App.fireEvent('getFeed');
    Ti.App.fireEvent('showFeed');

    Ti.API.info('Response: ' + response.message);

}, function(error) {
    alert('There was an error. Please try again later.');
});
```

};

When the data arrives on the server it is inserted directly into the posts along with other data table using the following code:

`@user = User.find(session[:user_id])
@post = @user.posts.create(params[:post].merge(:val1 => @val1, :val2 => @val2, :group_id => @groupId ).permit(:val3, :val4, :time, :val5, :val5, :group_id, :comment, :image64))`

To see what was sent from the app, the image as a base64 string was saved to a file.  Here is an extract of that
`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDACgcHiMeGSgjISMtKygwPGRBPDc3PHtYXUlkkYCZlo+AjIqgtObDoKrarYqMyP/L2u71////m8H////6/+b9//j/2wBDASstLTw1PHZBQXb4pYyl+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj4+Pj/wAA`

The post[image64] value is arriving and saving in the database as this:
`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDACgcHiMeGSgjISMtKygwPGRBPDc3PHtYXUlkkYCZlo AjIqgtObDoKrarYqMyP/L2u71////m8H////6/ b9//j/2wBDASstLTw1PHZBQXb4pYyl Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj4 Pj/wAA`

Note that the sent string contains Pj4+Pj4+ and the string at the server end turns into Pj4 Pj4 .  The + character has been removed.  My guess is this and possibly some other alteration to the string is causing the problem.

Has anyone seen this before and how can I ensure that the string sent to the server and save in the database are the same.  IE not altered.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very fragile and error prone way to send a file in a request:  maybe you should be using an enctype='multipart/form-data' form instead?  It will save you a lot of mucking about with string formatting.

http://digipiph.com/blog/submitting-multipartform-data-using-jquery-and-ajax

Your problem is that Rails automatically calls `CGI.unescape(val)` on any parameter value:  this "unescapes" the + symbols into spaces, since spaces are normally encodes as "+" symbols in a url.

The multipart encoding might stop it doing this - give it a go.